# How to remove the square brackets from a list when it is printed/output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a piece of code that does everything I need it to do and now I am making it look better and refining it. When I print the outcome, I find that the list in the statement is in square brackets and I cannot seem to remove them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map()` to convert the numbers to strings, and use `" ".join()` or `", ".join()` to place them in the same string:

```
mylist = [4, 5]
print(" ".join(map(str, mylist)))
#4 5
print(", ".join(map(str, mylist)))
#4, 5
```

You could also just take advantage of the `print()` function:

```
mylist = [4, 5]
print(*mylist)
#4 5
print(*mylist, sep=", ")
#4, 5
```

Note: In Python2, that won't work because `print` is a statement, not a function.  You could put `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning of the file, or you could use `import __builtin__; getattr(__builtin__, 'print')(*mylist)`

Comment: Just used it and the first one worked fine, i tried the print and it's a bit too long for what it is, so i'll stick to the first one:)

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

If `print` is a function (which it is by default in Python 3), you could [unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls) the list with `*`:

```
>>> L = [3, 5]
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(*L)
3 5
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work in 2.7.11, i just get a syntax error.

Comment: @Jack make sure you run the `import` statement before calling `print()`.

Comment: I've figured why I got an error now, i need to print lots of different things at once in one sentence so this won't work for what i need, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it to a string instead of printing the list directly:

```
print(", ".join(LIST))
```

If the elements in the list are not strings, you can convert them to string using either repr() or str() :

```
LIST = [1, "printing", 3.5, { "without": "brackets" }]
print( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in LIST ) )
```

Which gives the output:

```
1, 'printing', 3.5, {'without': 'brackets'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do smth like this:

```
separator = ','
print separator.join(str(element) for element in myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you display the elements in the list one by one using the for loop instead of displaying an entire list at once like so:

```
# l - list
for i in range(0, len(l)):
    print l[i],
```

Comment: I'll try it, i think i'll stick to the list for simplicity though as i would only really have 3/4 numbers in a list, thanks anyway